# Iptables Rules for NFS Server and NFS Client

Tags: iptables, nfsclient

Without `iptables` rules I am able to mount my `NFSSERVER:/PATH` but with it(`firewall`/`iptables`) enabled I am not able to mount.

```
[.e.g., after iptables --flush/ firewaalld stop ; mount NFSSERVER:/Path works ]
```

I am not supposed to disable/clear the `firewall`/`iptables` but I am allowed to open a port. What is the rule that I need to add to open up the port/mount?

Current default policy is `DROP all INCOMING/OUTGOING/FORWARD` and there are couple of rules to allow wget from external 80 port etc.,

adding the NFS Server port didnt help.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 2049 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 2049 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 2049 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 2049 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Thanks.

PS: This is for `nfs` client not `NFS` server machine.

Comment: This doesn't work since `nfsd` is not the only daemon that requires network access. Other daemons involved in `NFS` are `portmap`, `statd`, `mountd`, `lockd` and `rquotad`. See [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NFS-HOWTO/security.html#FIREWALLS) and [this](http://rlworkman.net/howtos/NFS_Firewall_HOWTO) for example.

Answer (score 8):

If all you need is NFS version 4 (which is already over 10 years old), you don't need to go to all of the effort described in @Sathish's answer. Just make sure TCP port 2049 is open the server's firewall, and that the client's firewall allows outbound traffic to port 2049 on the server.

CentOS 5 (also old) has a nice [explanation](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-nfs.html) of why NFSv4 is more firewall friendly than v3 and v2.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

**NFS SERVER:**

Configure Ports for rquotd(875/udp; 875/tcp), lockd(32803/tcp; 32769/udp), mountd(892/udp; 892/tcp), statd(10053/udp; 10053/tcp), statd_outgoing(10054/udp; 10054/tcp)

```
    vim /etc/sysconfig/nfs
```

If desired, disable NFS v3 and NFS v2 suport by editing lines 5 & 6 of /etc/sysconfig/nfs

```
    MOUNTD_NFS_V2="no"
    MOUNTD_NFS_V3="no"
```

Save current Iptables rules for later use. (if iptables-save is absent in your distribution, you may try iptables -S filename )

```
    iptables-save > pre-nfs-firewall-rules-server
```

Flush and check Iptables rules

```
    iptables -F
    iptables -L
```

Stop and Start NFS and related Services in the following sequence

```
   service rpcbind stop
   service nfslock stop
   service nfs stop
   service rpcbind start
   service nfslock start
   service nfs start
```

Make sure the configured NFS and its associated ports shows as set before and notedown the port numbers and the OSI layer 4 protcols. The standard port numbers for rpcbind (or portmapper) are 111/udp, 111/tcp and nfs are 2049/udp, 2049/tcp.

```
   rpcinfo -p | sort -k 3
```

Restore the pre-nfs-firewall-rules now

```
   iptables-restore < pre-nfs-firewall-rules-server
```

Write iptables rules for NFS server (Note: Loopback adapter has to allowed, else you will see packets dropped and also when you restart nfs service, it will spit ***ERROR*** {Starting NFS quotas: Cannot register service: RPC: Timed out rpc.rquotad: unable to register (RQUOTAPROG, RQUOTAVERS, udp). [FAILED]} for rquotad daemon. You can check this by adding a rule with LOG jump target at the bottom of INPUT or OUTPUT chains of filter table)

```
   iptables -P INPUT DROP
   iptables -P OUTPUT DROP 
   iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp -m multiport --dports 10053,111,2049,32769,875,892 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
   iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 10053,111,2049,32803,875,892 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
   iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp -m multiport --sports 10053,111,2049,32769,875,892 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
   iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 10053,111,2049,32803,875,892 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
   iptables -I INPUT  -i lo -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -I OUTPUT  -o lo -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -L -n --line-numbers
```

Configure NFS exports directory

```
   vim /etc/exports 
   exportfs -av
   showmount -e
   rpcinfo -p
```

Stop and Start NFS and related Services in the following sequence

```
   service rpcbind stop
   service nfslock stop
   service nfs stop
   service rpcbind start
   service nfslock start
   service nfs start
```

**NFS CLIENT:**

Save current Iptables rules for later use. (if iptables-save is absent in your distribution, you may try iptables -S filename )

```
   iptables-save > pre-nfs-firewall-rules-client
```

Flush and check Iptables rules

```
   iptables -F
   iptables -L
```

Obtain the firewalled NFS Server ports from the client machine and notedown the port numbers and the OSI layer 4 protcols.

```
   rpcinfo -p 'ip-addr-nfs-server' | sort -k 3
```

Restore the pre-nfs-firewall-rules now

```
   iptables-restore < pre-nfs-firewall-rules-client
```

Write iptables rules for NFS client (Note: Loopback adapter has to allowed, else you will see packets dropped and also when you restart nfs service, it will spit ***ERROR*** {Starting NFS quotas: Cannot register service: RPC: Timed out rpc.rquotad: unable to register (RQUOTAPROG, RQUOTAVERS, udp). [FAILED]} for rquotad daemon. You can check this by adding a rule with LOG jump target at the bottom of INPUT or OUTPUT chains of filter table)

```
   iptables -P INPUT DROP
   iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
   iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp -m multiport --sports 10053,111,2049,32769,875,892 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
   iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 10053,111,2049,32803,875,892 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
   iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp -m multiport --dports 10053,111,2049,32769,875,892 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
   iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 10053,111,2049,32803,875,892 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
   iptables -I INPUT  -i lo -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -I OUTPUT  -o lo -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -L -n --line-numbers
```

Stop and Start NFS and related Services in the following sequence

```
   service rpcbind stop
   service nfslock stop
   service nfs stop
   service rpcbind start
   service nfslock start
   service nfs start
```

List NFS Server exports

```
   showmount -e 'ip-addr-nfs-server'
```

Mount NFS Exports manually (persistent mounts can be configured using /etc/fstab)

```
   mount -t nfs ip-addr-nfs-server:/exported-directory /mount-point -o rw,nfsvers=3
   mount -t nfs ip-addr-nfs-server:/exported-directory /mount-point -o rw  --> For NFS4 version
```

Configure autofs, if automounting is preferred for nfs exports and with ldap user home directories (Direct and Indirect Maps can be set)

```
   vim /etc/auto.master    -> specify the mount point and map-name (Eg: auto.nfs)
   vim /etc/map-name
   service autofs stop
   service autofs start
```

Check mounted NFS Exports

```
   df -h -F nfs
   mount | grep nfs
```

List all pseudo root NFS-V4 export directories (NFS Lazy mount)

```
   ls /net/ip-addr-nfs-server
```

Comment: The `ls /net/ip-addr-nfs-server` command might not work if the server has NFSv3 disabled. The automounter uses `showmount` to determine if a server is exporting NFS folders, and a pure NFSv4 server wont be reachable this way, as showmount will report `RPC: Program not registered`, thus prevening autofs from showing anything under the virtual `/net` directory.