# Boot from NFS server with UBoot

Tags: nfs

I have a problem with an NFS server. I basically have to boot an embedded processor from NFS.
On an ubuntu machine I simply put the filesystem in /tftpboot, 
added in /etc/exports this line:

```
/tftpboot *(rw,no_root_squash,no_all_squash,sync)
```

then I executed the commands:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/exportfs -av

sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-server restart
```

but on the embedded processor I get this error:

```
Looking up port of RPC 100003/2 on 192.168.2.11
Looking up port of RPC 100005/1 on 192.168.2.11
VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS, trying floppy.
VFS: Cannot open root device "nfs" or unknown-block(2,0)
Please append a correct "root=" boot option
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,0)
```

in particular the lines

```
Looking up port of RPC 100003/2 on 192.168.2.11
Looking up port of RPC 100005/1 on 192.168.2.11
```

make me think that the problem is in the configuration of the NFS server, anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had today exactly the same problem with an old embedded device and an NFS Server installed on SUSE Leap.
I sniffed the communication with Wireshark and it gave me an idea of what went wrong.
In my case the problem had to do with **"iptable filter**" and **"NFS server version"**:

1. Configure **iptables** to open the NFS related ports at the NFS server side
2. My device only supported **version 2 of NFS**, and SUSE NFS server was configured by  default to support v3 and v4.

To solve **1**:
You can check post
[Iptables Rules for NFS Server and NFS Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187345/iptables-rules-for-nfs-server-and-nfs-client)

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 172.17.200.26/16 -d 172.17.200.26/16 -p udp -m multiport --dports 10053,111,2049,32769,875,892,20048,950 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 172.17.200.26/16 -d 172.17.200.26/16 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 10053,111,2049,32803,875,892,20048,950 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -s 172.17.200.26/16 -d 172.17.200.26/16 -p udp -m multiport --sports 10053,111,2049,32769,875,892,20048,950 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -s 172.17.200.26/16 -d 172.17.200.26/16 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 10053,111,2049,32803,875,892,20048,950 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

To solve **2**  You can check:
https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP1/html/SLES-all/cha-nfs.html#sec-nfs-configuring-nfs-server

Enable NFS version 2 on the server by modifying */etc/sysconfig/nfs* by setting:

```
NFSD_OPTIONS="-V2"
MOUNTD_OPTIONS="-V2
```

I hope it helps someone, i lost  some hours with this issue

I add a screenshot of problem 2 which was found because of wireshark capture:
[image]